# Why am I getting Overflow Error? VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

Why do I get this "Overflow" error when trying to output certain results towards the Excel file?

```
        'calculating the total CGs across all of the bays
        For ii = 1 To bayCount
            .cells(bayCount + 2, 3) = .cells(bayCount + 2, 3) + .cells(ii + 1, 2) * .cells(ii + 1, 3)
            .cells(bayCount + 2, 4) = .cells(bayCount + 2, 4) + .cells(ii + 1, 2) * .cells(ii + 1, 4)
            .cells(bayCount + 2, 5) = .cells(bayCount + 2, 5) + .cells(ii + 1, 2) * .cells(ii + 1, 5)
        Next ii
       .cells(bayCount + 2, 3) = .cells(bayCount + 2, 3) / .cells(bayCount + 2, 2)
       .cells(bayCount + 2, 4) = .cells(bayCount + 2, 4) / .cells(bayCount + 2, 2)
       .cells(bayCount + 2, 5) = .cells(bayCount + 2, 5) / .cells(bayCount + 2, 2)
```

What I'm looking for is just to get the results from the previous calculations and fill the excel sheet. I was told that it could be the size of the numbers that might be exceeding the limits.

Comment: Which row throws the error?  What is `bayCount`? How is it defined? How is `ii` defined? They both should be defined as `Long`. Do you use `Option Explicit`?

Comment: Likely either your `ii` and `bayCount` variables are `Integer`s and should be `Long`, or you're performing a calculation that equates to 0/0. My guess is the second.

Comment: When it fails what are the values of the various cells referenced in the failing line?

Comment: Yes I do have Option Explicit. Should I remove it? What does it do?

Comment: So the debug function highlights the line below "Next ii". I tried changing the numbers but I still get the same error.

Comment: Baycount is an integer which is equal to 30 right now.

Comment: After `Next ii`, add `Debug.Print .cells(bayCount + 2, 3).Value, .cells(bayCount + 2, 2).Value` and inspect the output in the Immediate Window.

Comment: Also, change any instance of `Integer` to `Long`.

Comment: I changed these variables from Integer to Long, but I get another error saying "ByRef argument type mismatch"

Comment: On which line ?